# DTFT properties of sequence x(n)?

Tags: fft

I have a sequence `-x(-n)`. I need to calculate dtft from this sequence

According to DTFT properties I `x(-n)` this is `X(e^-jw)`, but what about `-x(-n)`? As I understood it should be `-X(e^-jw)`.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: DFT/FFT is *linear* so `FFT(-1 * x) == -1 * FFT(x)`. If you have a way of calculating the time-reversed DFT, then the negative sign in front is trivial to accommodate. (You say ‘DTFT’ but presumably you mean sampling the DTFT using the DFT since  you want to do this on a computer?)